# Are the groups $SU(2, ℂ)$ and $U(1, ℍ)$ isomorphic?

Tags: lie-groups, quaternions, unitary-matrices

Both these groups are double covers of $SO(3, ℝ)$ so they must share the same Lie Algebra at least.

More generally if 2 Lie groups share a Lie algebra, and both are N-covers of another group, are the two groups isomorphic?

Comment: $\pi_1(SO(3, \mathbb{R})) = \mathbb{Z}_2$, so if what you say is true, then they are compact simply connected Lie groups with the same Lie algebra and are therefore isomorphic. What do you mean by $U(1, \mathbb{H})$? Do you mean $Sp(1)$?

Comment: I do not know about your more general question, but lots of isogenies to orthogonal groups are catalogued at http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/sporadic_isogenies.pdf

Comment: @Michael Albanese I mean the group of Unit quaternions. Which I think is simply connected almost trivially, correct?

Comment: You will find `\mathbf` useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have an explicit isomorphism, consider $\Bbb H$ with the usual basis $1,i,j,k$ over $\Bbb R$, instead as a vector space over $\Bbb C$ with basis $1,j$. Then the quaternion $q:=(x+iy)+j(z+iw)$, $x,y,z,w\in\Bbb R$, acts by  left multiplication  on the basis elements $1$, respectively $j$, as the row components of the matrix
$$
A(q)
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x+iy & z+iw\\
-z+iw & x-iy
\end{bmatrix}
$$
show it. So it induces a $\Bbb C$-algebra homomorphism from $\Bbb H$ to $M_2(\Bbb C)$, the algebra of $2\times 2$ matrices with complex components. The squared norm of a quaternion corresponds to the determinant, 
$$
|q|^2 =x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2 = (x+iy)(x-iy)-(z+iw)(-z+iw)=\det A(q)\ ,
$$
so the norm one quaternions (versors) correspond to elements in $\operatorname{SU}(2,\Bbb C)$. The (restriction of the) map $A$ defines the needed isomorphism.

A simplest counterexample would be the $2:1$ cover of $S^1=\{\ z\in\Bbb C\ :\ |z|=1\ \}$ given elementwise by $z\to z^2$, and the disconnected cousin $\{\pm 1\}\times S^1$.

Comment: Where is w? I think you dropped in it your first definition

Comment: Yes, thanks for the point, i changed my mind from the form $x+iy+jz+kw$ to the form $(x+iy)+j(\dots)$, and during the edit the $w$ was removed instead of $k$.

Answer (score 3):

$SU(2)$ and $U(1, \mathbb{H})$ are isomorphic. However, it is not true that two Lie groups having isomorphic Lie algebras and being $N$-covers of another Lie group are isomorphic. For example, both $SU(2)\times SO(3)$ and $SO(4)$ are double covers of $SO(3)\times SO(3)$, and have Lie algebras isomorphic to $\mathfrak{su}(2)\oplus\mathfrak{su}(2)$, but they are not isomorphic.